# Parsing binary file in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to parse a binary file which stores various types of records.Main goal is rasterize this geometry file in Angular page. Example of Point and Line structure present in the binary file:

```
struct Point
{
    uint8_t PointType;
    float X,Y,Z;    
    uint32_t Color;
    float PointSize;
};

struct Line
{
    uint8_t LineType;
    float X,Y,Z;   
    uint32_t Color; 
    float LineWidth;
    uint16_t StrokeType;
};
```

These are packed structures. Since [Basic Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) do not include byte, signed byte, word etc. , What are my options to parse this binary file? I know I can parse it by reading each field from buffer, but that means I have to write a function for each record type. That results 56 functions in my case excluding complex records(e.g. Tree Structured Records, Data Tables). Is there any work around?

Comment: Be careful! This next step is *very* complicated, so follow me closely. `uint8_t` => `number`, `float` => `number`, `uint32_t` => `number`, `uint16_t` => `number`. Basically, everything is just `number`. However, seeing the names of these fields, you might want to consider using enums for StrokeType and LineType.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But that means I have to write a function for each record type.  Is there any other way? Like, using WASM can help me here?

Comment: Is this a binary file or text file? Are you trying to parse each "struct"?

Comment: It is a binary file.